# How do I Map and Remap string values to Int or double in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data file of some columns. I am performing some mathematical computations on the values for that purpose I want to map my non Integer value columns to Int and then after the operations on the values I want to remap them.
Following are my columns values

```
atom_id,molecule_id,element,type,charge
d100_1,d100,c,22,-0.128
d100_10,d100,h,3,0.132
d100_11,d100,c,29,0.002
d100_12,d100,c,22,-0.128
d100_13,d100,c,22,-0.128
```

Suppose I want to map only 2 columns and then remap those columns values only. I have searched for methods and found String Indexer but it maps all of the columns of the DF, I need to map only specific columns and then remap the values of those specific columns. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//edited Part
```

I have the following columns in my DataFrame

```
ind1,inda,logp,lumo,mutagenic,element
1,0,4.23,-1.246,yes,c
1,0,4.62,-1.387,yes,b
0,0,2.68,-1.034,no,h
1,0,6.26,-1.598,yes,c
1,0,2.4,-3.172,yes,a
```

Basically I am writing the code for synthetic Data Generation based on the given input data, so I want to use column values i.e ind1,inda,logp,lumo,mutagenic,element. single row at a time and after applying some math functions on it I will get a row which will consist of 6 values and each value will be representing the corresponding column value.
Now the problem is that all column values are of type double except mutagenic and element. I want to map this mutagenic and element columns to double values for example **yes to 0 and No to 1** so that I can use them and then when I will receive the output row then I will reverse map that generated mutagenic value back to the corresponding string value using that mapping function.
***Hope so I am clear this time***

Comment: can you add expected output ??

Comment: @Srinivas I have added more detail can you please check it?

Comment: still not clear to me. can you write code using sample i/p that you have?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I have made some changes May be I am clear this time :)